# Quickly rotate object with mouse in Sketch

Tags: sketch-app

In Illustrator you can quickly rotate objects with the cursor. If you hover close to a corner this rotate tool appears:
[image]

In Sketch you always have to switch to the rotate tool which I find kind of annoying. Is there a way to get this behavior in Sketch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can press the <kbd>cmd</kbd> key while hovering on a corner of a box to make appear a rotation cursor instead of a resize icon and then apply a rotation on it by moving your mouse (it might be the same behavior as the one in Illustrator).

Here's a gif from this [article](https://medium.com/sketch-app-sources/use-your-shift-key-in-sketch-d4d98132e9b4) that shows you can also hold <kbd>shift</kbd> (while still holding <kbd>cmd</kbd> to apply a rotation by 15° each time you drag your mouse.

[image]

You can also click and then drag the box that contains the rotation value in the inspector panel (on the right) to quickly apply a rotation on an object without hovering it.

[image]